# show/hide a div using select in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have seen lots of post about this topic. My concern is, would it be possible if I place a jquery inside a div? It's like a jquery inside a div in which that div is shown/hidden using select in jquery. considering there are multiple of divs and each have different jquery. What would be the proper syntax for this if possible?

Comment: it is not clear what you want here. do u need to show div for which is selected and hide other 2 divs ...is it ??

Comment: The problem is not quite clear.. what is the functionality of inner jquery as you have written "jquery 1 here..."? You are saying "jquery inside div" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Khaleel yes.. I'm just wondering if its okay to place a jquery inside the divs. I want that jquery to work only on that particular div.

Comment: Note: `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

Comment: @LynerKharl You can place it everywhere, optimization tools suggest to put js before the body tag close, to use it only on that div is sufficient to set the correct ID

Comment: @Dheed so what should be the proper syntax? so its fine if I put the js inside the div and the js for the show/hide should I place it before the body tag close

Comment: @LynerKharl Take a look at my answer, it's pointless to split the javascript code all over the page, also because it could slow down the webpage load (when the js is heavy). However you have to active the js somehow: if you place your js without a trigger/calling event it will be executed when the page is loaded (not even at the end if you don't put the function inside a proper function call), I will update the answer

Comment: Nope, you cant place scripts inside Divs, you can always have selectors to apply script action on your selected div. give unique id to divs and achieve it easily

Comment: @LynerKharl I haveupdated the answer, hope it clarifies your doubt

Comment: @Dheed thanks now I get the whole picture

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(this).find(':selected').val()
```

instread of

```
$(this).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Normal page structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <style /> 
         <link />
    </head>
    <body>
         <link />
         <script>
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should place all the js that aren't inside a file at the bottom of the body, so the page will be loaded and the content willl be displayed.
If you put a js code inside the page as it is, like `alert('hi');` it will be executed once the browser reaches that rendering point, this could lead to problems if the js code points to an uncompleted html rendered node (like a div that is inserted after the js code), that's why people usually wrap their code inside `$( document ).ready(function() {}` function to run the code once the document is ready.
If you want to run a specific js after an event (like show a div) you have to wrap it inside a calling event function (like `.change()` or `.onclick`).
Basically:

- 'Free' code will be executed once the page reach that point
- 'Wrapped' code will be execute when the event is triggered

Example:

```
<div>
    <script> alert('hi');</script>
</div>
```

The code will be execute once the page load reach that point, even if the div is hidden or not

```
<div id='test'>
     <script> $('#test').onclick(function(){alert('hi');})</script>
</div>
```

The js will be trigger once you click on the div, even if the div is hidden or not
**ORIGINAL**

I haven't uderstood your question, however these are the possibilities:

1) **Show a code and hide/show div**: [JSFiddle - Running Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bzuo2j17/)

HTML

```
<select id="choice">
    <option value="1" selected>one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<div id="1" class="hidden"> some codes <xmp><script>jquery 1 here...</script></xmp></div>
<div id="2" class="hidden"> some codes <xmp><script>jquery 2 here...</script></xmp></div>
<div id="3" class="hidden"> some codes <xmp><script>jquery 3 here...</script></xmp></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
.chosen{
    display:block;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#choice').change(function(){
        if( $('.chosen').length >0){
            $('.chosen').removeClass('chosen');
        }
        $('#' + $(this).val()).addClass('chosen');
    });
});
```

**2) Run a code when div is selected**: [JSFiddle - Running Example](http://jsfiddle.net/htbhx93p/2/)
HTML:

```
<select id="choice">
    <option value="1" selected>one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#choice').change(function(){
        switch($(this).val()){
            case '1':
                alert('1');
                break;
            case '2':
                alert('2');
                break;
            case '3':
                alert('3');
                break;
            default:
                alert('error');
        }

         //if/else structure
        /* var val=parseInt($(this).val());
         if( val==1){
             alert('1');
         }
         else if(val==2){
             alert('2');
         }
         else{
             alert('3');
         }*/

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one Example of What you are looking for...

**HTML:**

```
<select id="thechoices">
<option value="box1">Box 1</option>
<option value="box2">Box 2</option>
<option value="box3">Box 3</option>
<option value="all">All Boxes</option>
</select>

<div id="boxes">
<div id="box1"><p>Box 1 stuff...</p></div>
<div id="box2"><p>Box 2 stuff...</p></div>
<div id="box3"><p>Box 3 stuff...</p></div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box1').hide();
    $('#box2').hide();
    $('#box3').hide();
    $("#thechoices").change(function(){
    if(this.value == 'all')
    {$("#boxes").children().show();}
    else
    {$("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();}
    });

    $("#thechoices").change();
    });
```

### [Working Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/LL20pfat/)